# prometheus support in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, prometheus

I wanted to ask a question regarding database support in Laravel.

**Does Laravel 5 supports prometheus database?**

If not, then how we can add it into Laravel 5. Because in documentation, I have seen Laravel 5.6 supports only 4 databases:

1. MySQL
2. SQL Server
3. PostgreSQL
4. SQLite

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/superbalist/laravel-prometheus-exporter

Comment: Next time please google it yourself

Comment: ok thanks. I will check it how to link it with laravel.